# How to retrieve a current user's OpenID Connect ID token via apex?

Tags: apex, oauth2, single-sign-on, authentication, open-id-connect

**Question:**

Is there any method for retrieving the current user's OpenId Connect (OIDC) Id Token via apex?

**Background Context / Goal:**

My goal is to set up Single logout for a salesforce community that is connected to an OpenID Connect Okta Authorization server.

**Previous Attempts**

I attempted following Salesforce Documentation ['Configure OpenID Connect Settings for Single Logout Where Salesforce Is the Relying Party'](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.security_auth_slo_oidc_rp_configuring.htm&type=5).  The Auth. Provider Custom logout url was not working as expected for the community (when we attempt to logout via this url, the id_token_hint does not get passed to the logout endpoint as Okta expects it to).

**Current Attempt:**

I am trying to make a custom component that has an anchor element with an href set to the single logout get request in the [Okta](https://help.okta.com/en/prod/Content/Topics/Apps/Apps_Single_Logout.htm) provided format, but there doesn't seem to be a way to retrieve the id token via salesforce apex:

```
GET https://{baseUrl}/logout?id_token_hint=${id_token}&post_logout_redirect_uri=${post_logout_redirect_uri}&state=${state}
```

Comment: Have you considered trying AuthToken class? I don't have time to test at the moment but checkout the getAccessToken(authProviderId, providerName) method. (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_class_Auth_AuthToken.htm)

Comment: @Sarah Ganci: Did you ever find a solution for this? I'm also looking for a way to get the id_token, but can't find one so far.

Comment: The AuthToken class only returns the access token, which does not help in this scenario.

Comment: +1. Assuming by the lack of response that this is not possible in Apex. Seems to be quite a restriction.