# How to retrieve id_token from APEX OIDC Auth Provider

Tags: apex, identity, open-id-connect, azure-active-directory

We are using Azure as Identity Provider and did the OIDC Setup. Configured Auth.Provider with Azure Credentials. We were able to generate the Access token from the Auth.RegistrationHandler, but we need to capture "id_token" to exchange with one of our internal API, this is what being expected. There seems to be no way to retrieve the id_token that was returned by the Authorization Server / IDP. I have been looking for any help in salesforce documentation to capture the id_token that was returned by the Authorization server/IdP but there is none found. Also connected with support team they didn't help either. Can someone help me with this.

Also I have seen same question being asked in different forms but it never resolved.

[Salesforce Apex OIDC Auth Provider - How to retrieve id_token](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/359002/salesforce-apex-oidc-auth-provider-how-to-retrieve-id-token/402002#402002)

[How to retrieve a current user's OpenID Connect ID token via apex?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/332366/how-to-retrieve-a-current-users-openid-connect-id-token-via-apex)